# Spring Boot - Is there a way to extend yml file in a microservice from another microservice?

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, microservices

I have a common microservice (used by other microservices) and two other microservices for authentication and general APIs.
The microservices have a lot of common properties and I would like to place these common properties in the common microservice yml file, then extend into the yml of the other microservices, is there an easy way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Spring Cloud Config? https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config

In your case you could use it for general properties as well as application specific if desired.